# Entity Framework Regex Mismatch

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hey guys I'm currently putting together a simple ASP.NET MVC Form. For the First and Last name I'm trying to ensure that only letters a-zA-Z can be used and that a minimum and maximum of 1-50 characters can be used, However I constantly seem to have a Regex Mismatch.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name.")]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name should not be longer than 50 characters.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]{1, 50}$")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

I have tested the Regex statement in a few online calculators which tell me this is corect however the Mismatch always appears when testing the Form.

Any Ideas? Is the Regex Correct?

Comment: I would vote against such a restriction. But I guess you made a typo, you need to use `^[a-zA-Z]{1,50}$`, [*`{1, 50}` matches the characters `{1, 50}` literally*](https://regex101.com/r/qJ7lK1/1).

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for the quick reply. Forgive me, but isnt that not what I alread have? Also I'm interested, in why you woulde vote against such a restriction? could you suggest an alternate?

Comment: Sorry I get what you mean about the {1, 50} being literal position matches. Appologies.

Comment: Look at Wiktors surname ...

Comment: Ahh ok ok^^ .. Thanks for the quick replies guys.

Comment: The `\w` in a .NET regex matches `ж` and `ą`, and any other base Unicode letter. As well as digits and `_`. If you need to match any letter, it must be `\p{L}`. Use `@"\A\p{L}{1,50}\z"` (note it is not supported by JavaScript regex engine, server-side validation only can be performed with it).

Answer (score 0):

Again guys thanks for the tip on this one. In keeping with Wiktor's suggestion I have fixed what was actually a misunderstanding about Regex and not actually a typo :S
But also I have now allowed for Non-English characters such as á é etc

^[a-zA-Z-_ ’'‘ÆÐƎƏƐƔĲŊŒẞÞǷȜæðǝəɛɣĳŋœĸſßþƿȝĄƁÇĐƊĘĦĮƘŁØƠŞȘŢȚŦŲƯY̨Ƴąɓçđɗęħįƙłøơşșţțŧųưy̨ƴÁÀÂÄǍĂĀÃÅǺĄÆǼǢƁĆĊĈČÇĎḌĐƊÐÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒĘẸƎƏƐĠĜǦĞĢƔáàâäǎăāãåǻąæǽǣɓćċĉčçďḍđɗðéèėêëěĕēęẹǝəɛġĝǧğģɣĤḤĦIÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨĮỊĲĴĶƘĹĻŁĽĿʼNŃN̈ŇÑŅŊÓÒÔÖǑŎŌÕŐỌØǾƠŒĥḥħıíìiîïǐĭīĩįịĳĵķƙĸĺļłľŀŉńn̈ňñņŋóòôöǒŏōõőọøǿơœŔŘŖŚŜŠŞȘṢẞŤŢṬŦÞÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮŲỤƯẂẀŴẄǷÝỲŶŸȲỸƳŹŻŽẒŕřŗſśŝšşșṣßťţṭŧþúùûüǔŭūũűůųụưẃẁŵẅƿýỳŷÿȳỹƴźżžẓ]{1,50}$

This works perfect for me now :). Thanks again Wiktor.

Comment: \w - Matches any word character.

Comment: Even better, Thanks again Alex^^ . Guess I need to spend more than a day or 2 with regex strings to understand more. Your a Gent.